# How to set multiple colours in a ggplot2 stat_summary plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I use `ggplot2` with `stat_summary` to show colours of my choice? Eg.:

```
simVol  <- data.frame(simId=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                      farm=rep(c('farm A', 'farm A', 'farm B', 'farm B'),2),
                      period=rep(1:2,4), 
                      volume=c(9,21,12,18,10,22,11,19))

P10meanP90 <- function(x) data.frame(
  y = mean(x), 
  ymin = quantile(x, .1),
  ymax = quantile(x, .9)
)
```

This command plots the distribution of volume at each farm against the period, using default colours:

```
ggplot(simVol, aes(x=period, y=volume, colour=farm)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.data="P10meanP90", geom="smooth", size=2)
```

However, if I add `colour='green'` to the arguments of `stat_summary`, it plots instead the aggregate across farms. I've tried using `colour=c('green','orange')`, but this still only shows a green line.

How do I change the colours in this plot?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scale_colour_manual` is the function you're looking for. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html

```
ggplot(simVol, aes(x=period, y=volume, colour=farm)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data="P10meanP90", geom="smooth", size=2) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect - thanks! In fact I'm also using the `fill` argument to provide a colour for the P10-P90 range.  Is there a way to provide different values for that for each farm too? thanks!

Comment: @RacingTadpole I added a link to the docs for `scale_colour_manual` and the other functions which control scales for different aesthetics.  Look at `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried `ggplot(simVol, aes(x=period, y=volume, colour=farm)) + stat_summary(fun.data="P10meanP90", geom="smooth", size=2) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "orange")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan", "pink"))` and the fill is still grey - am I using it wrong?

Comment: You have to map a variable to the `fill` aesthetic. Change the first part to `ggplot(simVol, aes(x = period, y = volume, colour = farm, fill = farm))`