# ggplot2: multiple colours in stat_summary

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot in which I am displaying individual values from multiple subjects, coloured by group. Added to that are means per group, calculated using stat_summary.

I would like the two means to be coloured by group, but in colours other than the individual data. This turns out to be difficult, at least when using stat_summary. I have the following code:

```
ggplot(data=dat, 
       aes(x=Round, y=DV, group=Subject, colour=T1)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1.5,
               linetype="dotted", color="black",
               aes(group=T1))
```

Which produces this [example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARCiQ.png).

The colour for the means created by stat_summary is set to black; otherwise it would be red and blue like the individual data lines. However, it is not possible to set more than one colour - so color=c("black", "blue") does not work.

I've already tried scale_colour_manual as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817856/how-to-set-multiple-colours-in-a-ggplot2-stat-summary-plot), but this will change the colours of the individual data lines, leaving the mean lines unaffected.

Any suggestion how to solve this? Code and data [here](http://www.simoncolumbus.com/wp-content/2014/10/Analyses.zip).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create different values for the mapping to color:

```
ggplot(data=iris, 
       aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1.5,
               linetype="dotted", aes(color=paste("mean", Species)))
```

[image: resulting plot]

You can then use `scale_color_manual` to get specific colors.

Comment: Thanks! That's brilliant. 

For the record (because that took me another moment to figure out), the grouping needs to remain intact, so the aes is aes(color=paste("mean", Role), group=Role).

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `aes(color=paste("mean", Role), group=Role)` why is there a need to include `"mean"`?

Comment: @TylerRuddenfort To have different colors for the means and to have the means appear separately in the legend.