# Using different colors for median lines and add as legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, median

This is in reference to the previous question by @simoncolumbus and answered by @Roland [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637735/ggplot2-multiple-colours-in-stat-summary). I tried to replicate this solution unsuccessfully. I got the error:

> "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval".

There are several previous posts about this error but in a different context. So please please do not mark this post as duplicate.

I have a data set of 600 respondents. I have an indicator variable with values for each of the 600 respondents across 5 years - 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017. Also, I have a city column for each respondent. This is a factor variable with 3 levels.

I have created a plot, plotting the indicator trend line for each of the 600 respondents, using 3 colors corresponding to the city the respondent belongs to. The Y-axis is the indicator value and X-axis has years. I have separated the colors of line graphs by cities.

I added 3 median indicator lines, such that there is a median line for respondents for each city. The median lines take the color of the trend lines for each group by default. This is a problem since the median line merges with the individual trend lines, making it difficult to distinguish. I want to use separate colors for median lines, and add this to the legend. I am using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

sample_no <- c(1:600)
city <- c(rep("A",150), rep("B",250), rep("C", 200))
indicator_2013 <- runif(600, min=0, max=1000)
indicator_2014 <- runif(600, min=0, max=1000)
indicator_2015 <- runif(600, min=0, max=1000)
indicator_2016 <- runif(600, min=0, max=1000)
indicator_2017 <- runif(600, min=0, max=1000)

df <- data.frame(sample_no, city, indicator_2013, indicator_2014, 
                 indicator_2015, indicator_2016, indicator_2017)
df1 <- df %>%
  gather(indicator_2013, indicator_2014, indicator_2015, indicator_2016, indicator_2017, 
         key="Year", value = "Indicator")

df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Indicator, color=city)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sample_no), alpha = .5, size = 0.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0.03)) + 
  labs(col = "City") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15,0.8), legend.background = element_blank()) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Indicator, group = city), 
               fun.y=median, geom = "line", linetype="dotted", size = 1, 
               aes(color = paste("median", city)))
```

Note: this is only dummy data so graphs are symmetric...

I added code `aes(color = paste("median", city))` inside stat_summary to help plot medians in diff colors and add those as the legend along with the legend of individual trend lines but I get the class uneval error. I also tried the `scale_color_manual` option outside of stat_summary but that changes the color of individual trend lines as well along with the medians - I need the individual trend line colors to be diff from median lines. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You have two separate `aes()` calls in `stat_summar()`. Try moving `color = paste("median", city)` inside the first one?

Comment: @Z.Lin, I have 2 aes(), not counting the third one I had added for distinguishing median colors, one for ggplot and one for geom_line. If I add color = paste("median", city) inside the ggplot aes() I get a warning message - The plyr::rename operation has created duplicates for the following name(s): (`colour`). The graph remains same. If I add it to the geom_line aes(), this begins to work except the colors for median lines and individual trend lines are interchanged i.e. the actual color for individual lines as per legend is the median line color as per legend and v.v.

Comment: I'm not referring to those. You have two `aes()` calls **inside** `stat_summary()`.

Comment: @Z.Lin, thanks! It was v. useful to learn about mapping diff aes() accurately.     The ordering of the legend gets distorted after it includes median lines and the default colors it was using were all merging with one another. I was able to achieve that with scale_color_manual(). scale_fill_manual() won't work as I have mapped a factor var to color. Just writing here in case someone else faced the same issue

Comment: Unable to see an option to accept your comment as answer